Find Viewers with Multiple Article Views in a Day
Using the table playground.views, write a SQL query to identify all viewers who viewed more than one article on the same day. The table includes columns viewer_id (the ID of the viewer), article_id (the ID of the article viewed), and view_date (the date of the view). The result should contain a single column named viewer_id, listing each viewer who meets the criteria without duplicates, and should be sorted in ascending order of viewer_id.
This is the table to query for this question:
CREATE TABLE playground.views
(
    article_id int
    ,author_id int
    ,viewer_id int
    ,view_date date 
)

INSERT INTO playground.views
(
    article_id
    ,author_id
    ,viewer_id
    ,view_date 
)
values
(1, 10, 1, '2024-12-01')
,(2, 11, 1, '2024-12-01')
,(3, 12, 1, '2024-12-01')
,(1, 10, 2, '2024-12-01')
,(1, 10, 3, '2024-12-01')

,(1, 10, 4, '2024-12-02')
,(2, 11, 4, '2024-12-02')
,(3, 12, 1, '2024-12-02')
,(1, 10, 1, '2024-12-02')
,(1, 10, 1, '2024-12-02')

I tried with the below SQL
SELECT
  viewer_id
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      viewer_id,
      view_date,
      count(article_id) AS number_of_arcticles
    FROM
      playground.views
    GROUP BY
      viewer_id,
      view_date
    HAVING
      count(article_id) > 1
  ) a
ORDER BY
  viewer_id ASC

But it gives more than the required number of rows.
I'm expecting:
viewer_id
1
4

but getting:
viewer_id
1
1
4


Please tag the RDBMS you are using... each has its own SQL dialect.

The issue is you are checking count but you should be checking distinct count of articles for unique articles.
SELECT
  viewer_id
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      viewer_id,
      view_date,
      count(distinct article_id) AS number_of_arcticles
    FROM
      playground.views
    GROUP BY
      viewer_id,
      view_date
    HAVING
      count(distinct article_id) > 1
  ) a
ORDER BY
  viewer_id ASC


Another way using SELF JOIN
Fiddle
SELECT DISTINCT v1.viewer_id
FROM views v1
JOIN views v2
    ON v1.viewer_id = v2.viewer_id
    AND v1.view_date = v2.view_date
    AND v1.article_id <> v2.article_id
ORDER BY v1.viewer_id;

Output


The easiest way to solve this issue is to use DISTINCT in the final SELECT statement like this:
SELECT DISTINCT
  viewer_id
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      viewer_id,
      view_date,
      count(article_id) AS number_of_arcticles
    FROM
      playground.views
    GROUP BY
      viewer_id,
      view_date
    HAVING
      count(article_id) > 1
  ) a
ORDER BY
  viewer_id ASC

